# How to stop form-mini.js from loading on pages?

Tags: magento2, search

I have a fully custom search done by myself, so I want to get rid of form-mini.js since its causing issues with my own version of search.

The problem is, I cant seem to override it, or remove it via `<remove>`

Any other ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`form-mini.js` is specified in `Magento_Search` module's `requirejs-config.js` and loaded dynamically by `require.js`

```
var config = {
    map: {
        '*': {
            quickSearch: 'Magento_Search/form-mini'
        }
    }
};
```

`quickSearch` is then called in `Magento_Search::form.mini.phtml` like this:

```
<input id="search"
       data-mage-init='{"quickSearch":{
            "formSelector":"#search_mini_form",
            "url":"<?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ $helper->getSuggestUrl()?>",
            "destinationSelector":"#search_autocomplete"}
       }'
       type="text"
       ...
       />
```

You can override `form.mini.phtml` in your theme and remove `data-mage-init` block from the input field. This would stop `form-mini.js` from loading.